# Commandline vimperator-like browser?

Tags: command-line, browser, vimperator

When browsing normally I use Firefox with [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/) installed, which gives you vim-like key bindings so you can browse without the mouse.

However, every now and again I have to browse from the commandline (often through SSH), and I've been using lynx for this, but it feels horribly inefficient after Vimperator - which would be perfect for doing this. Is there a CLI browser (text only, obviously), that works like Vimperator does?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can continue to use lynx for this. To change the key bindings, open up lynx, hit 'o' for options, and change the option `VI keys`[sic](under the third section) to ON.

```
[kevin@home-box ~]$ lynx --version
Lynx Version 2.8.5rel.1 (04 Feb 2004)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
Built on linux-gnu Oct 27 2008 15:54:32
[copyright info snipped]
[kevin@home-box ~]$
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can start lynx with vikeys argument:

```
lynx -vikeys
```

To start lynx with vi key binding turned on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know lynx, but I use [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) which I believe is a side-branch from the same original tree. It's very featureful and can be configured to work much like vimperator. The command-line browser that seemed to have the most vim-like bindings of those I encountered is [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/). It can do some things elinks can't (like display graphics in-page, with elinks you need to press a key to show them in an external viewer). But after trying w3m for a short while I went back to elinks---it was better-featured in respects that I cared about day-to-day. I don't want to sell either of them to you, just present some options.

Comment: `elinks` originated from `links` which was a better `lynx` .  (lynx originated in '92, and, to my knowledge, still doesn't render tables or frames.)  afaik links was a ground-up rewrite, not a lynx fork, but i don't know for sure.